# CSS: Make Flexbox's justify content only overflow to the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a dynamic number of divs in a single container div with `display: flex`.

Now, I want my child divs to be centered, so I use `justify-content: center`.
This works perfectly for a small number of children (the blue rectangles)

But for a larger amount of children, setting `justify-content: center` means that child divs are pushed farther and farther off-screen (the red rectangles).

Children pushed off-screen to the right are still visible because I can just scroll to the right to see the rightmost children.

But children pushed off-screen to the left are not visible because I cannot scroll to the left. This is a problem.

[image]

So essentially I want to use `flexbox` to center its children but prevent the children from being pushed off-screen to the left. Instead, content should overflow to the right, the way that `justify-content: flux-start` works, but still be centered.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: I didn't want to throw this in my question at the risk of being self-promotional, but it's for a client-side Trello clone that I made: http://reacto.surge.sh. As of writing I have `justify-content` set to `flux-start`, and I've been trying to center my columns :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use nested flex-containers and set `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` for inner flex-container. This will work because auto margins work only when we have free space to distribute. Demo:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.inner-flex {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* just styles for demo */
.flex__item {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="inner-flex">
    <div class="flex__item">One</div>
    <div class="flex__item">Two</div>
    <div class="flex__item">Three</div>
    <div class="flex__item">Four</div>
    <div class="flex__item">Five</div>
    <div class="flex__item">Six</div>
    <div class="flex__item">Seven</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5j51ftjj/) to test resizing.